# How does Reflection retrieve data assigned to variables?

Tags: c#, reflection

My understanding so far is that Reflection is used to retrieve the names of Types and their members from an assembly via its metadata. I've come across a few examples of Reflection in action identical to the following example.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Name = "John";
    Console.WriteLine(person.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(person)); //John
    person.Name = "Mary";
    Console.WriteLine(person.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(person)); //Mary
}
```

I understand how Reflection can get names of Types, members, etc. as this is what's stored in an assembly's metadata, but how does Reflection retrieve the value associated with it? This is dynamic data that changes during a program's execution (as shown in the example), which an assembly's metadata doesn't contain (right?).

Would be grateful for clarification on how Reflection retrieves actual values and whether this is actually the case. Please correct anything I've said that's not correct!

Answer (score 3):

The **short answer** is that reflection is a feature of the runtime, so it has access to runtime information. Were it a separate library with no runtime "hooks", you're right, it wouldn't be able to get the values of properties at runtime, or make calls, or anything else that wouldn't be essentially observable from the assembly file on disk.

**Long answer** where I prove this to myself:

Microsoft makes available a reference version of the C# source code used to write the base class libraries for .NET Framework. If we look at the `PropertyInfo.GetValue(object)` method you use in your example, it's defined [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/propertyinfo.cs,7f41c0c1ebadcc33). Following the trail of calls we eventually get to [an `abstract` method of the same name](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/propertyinfo.cs,445b1ae9553c5531) but different parameters. Further down in the source file is the implementing class, `RuntimePropertyInfo`, and [its override of `GetValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/propertyinfo.cs,ab24e8108206e7dc) we see that it is implemented by calling the property's `get` accessor (as, under the hood, properties are just collections of methods with certain signature conventions - `GetGetMethod` is a funny name meaning "get me the method defined as `get` for the current property"):

```
MethodInfo m = GetGetMethod(true);
if (m == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(System.Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_GetMethNotFnd"));
return m.Invoke(obj, invokeAttr, binder, index, null);
```

If we do a similar spelunking journey on `MethodInfo.Invoke`, we eventually reach [`RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtimehandles.cs,1925ccef0d79223f), which is declared:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal extern static object InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor);
```

The [`extern` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) on a class means "I don't have the body for this method in C#, look elsewhere for it". For most users of C# this means they're using [`DllImport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-6.0) to reference native code, but this method has a different attribute: [`MethodImpl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute?view=net-6.0), with the [`MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions?view=net-6.0) enum value. This is the C# way of saying to the compiler, "I don't have the body, but the actual runtime itself does".

So at the end of our journey we reach the point where the Reflection API relies on the runtime itself. Of course, the runtime and the base class libraries have to be developed in tandem to ensure these sync-up points exist.

Interestingly, the actual standard for .NET - [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) - makes the Reflection API optional, when the implementation (meaning the runtime + base class libraries) adheres to the bare minimum "Kernel Profile" (cite: 6th Ed., §IV.4.1.3). So actually there are implementations of .NET where you're *not* explicitly allowed to inspect the runtime like this, but given the reliance some kinds of applications have on reflection, all big implementations (original .NET Framework, .NET Core / the new .NET, and Mono) provide it.

Comment: You can follow `InternalCall` through in the latest version of `dotnet/runtime` on Github https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/coreclr. The docs for `InternalCall` are here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/24e7a4a1a101d91b6666dc6f44137574246fdd9c/docs/design/coreclr/botr/corelib.md#calling-from-managed-to-native-code look up the call in this file https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/vm/ecalllist.h then you probably want to go to here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/vm/runtimehandles.cpp next

Answer (score 2):

The TLDR is the CLR (Common Language Runtime) keeps track of all your objects in memory and when you call `GetValue` it retrieves the value for you.

Note [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects) is a little old, but here is a rough idea of what an object looks like in memory:

[image]

Please refer to the part that says `Object Instance`. An object laid out in memory, contains the following 4 items:

1. Syncblk
2. TypeHandle
3. Instance Fields
4. String Literals

When you call `GetValue`, using an `OBJECTREF` to the object instance, it finds the starting location where your instance fields are stored. From there it can figure out which instance to retrieve based on the type.

I believe the actual call is [FieldDesc::GetInstanceField](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/vm/field.cpp#L299).